# How to overwrite a file at bootup in linux?

Tags: linux, io-redirection

I am redirecting bootup logs from multiple places to a text file.i use (`>>`) append while redirecting so that existing content would not be overwritten during successive logging. How can I make sure that file *is* overwritten and a clean state is provided during bootup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, `>>` is for apending.

Use `>` to overwrite the file with the new content.

---

If you want to simply clear the log file *before* you start appending to it, use `echo "" > mylogfile` to truncate it to an empty string.

Comment: I think he needs to combine logs from different places but get fresh log every boot.

Comment: Yeah,my situation is exactly described by imslavko in the previous comment.

Comment: i guess if i do as suggested by meager i.e do a echo " " mylogfile before the first entry log entry in bootup sequence and use append(>>) in all the other places when i echo the content to mylogfile it'll do